# The accuracy rate of SVM classifier varies in different machines

Tags: python, matlab, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am using the [LIBSVM library](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/), a library for Support vector Machines compatible with both Python and Matlab to perform classification in a digit recognition algorithm and also a face recognition algorithm.

I am facing a very weird problem while performing SVM classification. **The accuracy rate of both training and testing varies drastically when I run the program in different computers** using the same code base, same interpreter (Python in my case) and same training and testing data.

Here is the code for only the function call for classification of the digit recognition algorithm (***Here Number of Training images = 1409 and Number of Test Images = 997***):

```
    from svmutil import *

    """Data for training"""
    train_features, train_labels = load_data('ocr_data/training/')

    """Data for testing"""
    test_features, test_labels = load_data('ocr_data/testing/')

    """Training a linear-SVM classifier"""
    train_features = train_features.tolist()
    test_features = test_features.tolist()


    problem = svm_problem(train_labels, train_features)
    parameter = svm_parameter('-t 0')

    model = svm_train(problem, parameter)
    svm_save_model('ocr.model', model)

    res = svm_predict(train_labels, train_features, model)
    res = svm_predict(test_labels, test_features, model)
```

The output for accuracy after training and testing are completed is given below for 4gb RAM/64 bit OS Windows 8:

```
Accuracy = 97.0901% (1368/1409) (classification) 
Accuracy = 35.6068% (355/997) (classification)
```

A different output for the same in Laptop of 2gb RAM/32-bit OS Windows 7:

```
Accuracy = 100.00% (1409/1409) (classification) 
Accuracy = 99.29% (990/997) (classification)
```

There are other variable accuracy outputs for some other computers which i am not including. I have also faced the same problem with another face recognition algorithm programmed in Matlab.

Is this is a generalized problem with SVM or am I doing something wrong. Also if this is a frequent problem with SVM classification please let me know what is the actual reason for this. Any solution is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have used LIBSVM a lot and never faced such problems. So, it is specific to your computer. Also, if your problem is 2-class, 35% accuracy is too low. Random prediction is 50%.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar My problem is 10-class.

Comment: Do you observe any difference if you test on two 64-bit / two 32-bit computers?

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar yes, i had mentioned it in my question description. The two outputs i have given are from 64-bit and 32-bit machines respectively.

Comment: In your question, you have mentioned, one 64-bit and another 32-bit. I am asking what if both were of 64-bit (or both 32-bit), do you still observe the discrepancy in results?

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar Oh sorry, actually i had got an accuracy of around 76% in another machine of 64-bit but windows 7 OS.

Comment: some ideas: python version mixup(2.x vs 3.x)? other library versions? data files with localisation problems?

Comment: @stefan I have used the same version of python 3.4.3 and its libraries too. I am also checking if the data loaded are same before calling svm.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including your data.

Comment: SVM is very sensitive to float accuracy and it seems to be likely the case in here and how python manage doubles on different architectures. You said you saw variance between two different 64 bit machines... Did you try in two different 32 bits machines? Was it more consistent?