# low SVM accuracy on train and test sets in python

Tags: python, matlab, machine-learning, scikit-learn, octave

I'm porting some matlab/octave scripts for support vector machines (SVMs) to python but I'm getting poor accuracy in one of two scripts with the sklearn method.

[`ex6_spam.py`](https://github.com/arturomp/coursera-machine-learning-in-python/blob/master/mlclass-ex6-004/mlclass-ex6/ex6_spam.py) loads some data trains a spam-detecting model.

In matlab, the [SVM code provided, `svmTrain.m,`](https://github.com/arturomp/coursera-machine-learning-in-python/blob/master/mlclass-ex6-004/mlclass-ex6/svmTrain.m) (see below for snippets) gives me ~99% accuracy in both the training and the test sets.

In python, [`sklearn.svm.SVM().fit()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.fit) is giving me ~56% if I just use their linear kernel, and ~44% if I precompute the Gram matrix for a linear kernel. (The data and code - `ex6_spam.py` - [are here](https://github.com/arturomp/coursera-machine-learning-in-python/tree/master/mlclass-ex6-004/mlclass-ex6).)

The odd thing, too, is that the exact same [piece of code](https://github.com/arturomp/coursera-machine-learning-in-python/blob/master/mlclass-ex6-004/mlclass-ex6/svmTrain.py) used in `ex6.py` gives me proper classification of 2D data points. Its behavior there is almost identical to the matlab/octave script.

I'm not doing much in `ex6_spam.py` - I load a training set:

```
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('spamTrain.mat')
X = mat["X"]
y = mat["y"]
```

I feed it to `sklearn.svm.SVM().fit()`:

```
C = 0.1
model = svmt.svmTrain(X, y, C, "linear") 
# this results in
#        clf = svm.SVC(C = C, kernel=kernelFunction, tol=tol, max_iter=max_passes, verbose=2)
#        return clf.fit(X, y)
```

and the I make a prediction:

```
p = model.predict(X)
```

The matlab/octave equivalent is

```
load('spamTrain.mat');

C = 0.1;
model = svmTrain(X, y, C, @linearKernel); # see the link to svmTrain.m above

p = svmPredict(model, X);
```

However, the results are wildly different. Any ideas why? I haven't had the chance to run it in a different computer, but maybe [that's a possible reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30499028/the-accuracy-rate-of-svm-classifier-varies-in-different-machines)?

Comment: Well, you have to be careful about the parameters / defaults. (1) matlab has ```autoscale=true``` by default, that's not the case in scikit-learn. So, if your data is not already standardized, you have to do it. (2) Maybe there are other differences too, some implementations use C, some 1/C. I'm not sure what's the case here. (3) I bet matlab also relies on liblinear or libsvm internally, so everything is just parameter-tuning! (Your ```piece-of-code``` link is dead)

Comment: thanks @sascha! (1) the features only take on the values 0 or 1, depending on the presence of a word in a document, so scaling won't do much (2) with C=10 (or 1e10) instead of C=0.1 results are almost identical! (~68% if I have C=1e-7 or 1e-16) (3) matlab prob. does rely on libsvm/liblinear/other libraries, but the matlab script I'm porting from uses a [simplified SVM method](https://github.com/arturomp/coursera-machine-learning-in-python/blob/master/mlclass-ex6-004/mlclass-ex6/svmTrain.m) (written by Stanford's Andrew Ng or his team) for Coursera exercises that doesn't call anything else

Comment: also, @sascha, I normalized/scaled the features just to see if that would change the result significantly, but I have the same accuracy ranges as I mentioned before =/

Comment: Well, if you are interested in obtaining better performance, there is not much you can do besides tuning parameters through cross-validation (especially C; sometimes the exact optimization-formulas differ; e.g. what variables are regularized -> this would mean, that 1/C might not be enough, even when C was the optimal value in the original approach). Besides there is also the possibility of changing the model-complexity using others kernels than linear. But i'm not sure if that's what you want to. Often it helps, but is very dependent on the data.